# What does it mean for a function to be continuous on its domain?

Tags: calculus, continuity, terminology, definition

I never understood the phrase "continuous on its domain."

Isn't everything continuous on its own domain, since the domain are all the $x$ values that we can plug into $f(x)$ and get a defined $y$ value back? i.e. doesn't the domain by definition tell you where the function is continuous? Why would the domain ever include something not continuous / not defined?

Comment: Being continuous doesn't mean being defined. You should review what the definition of continuity means; $f$ is continuous at $x$ if the limit of $f$ at $x$ exists and is equal to $f(x)$. There's nothing to guarantee that limit exists even if $f(x)$ is well-defined, and even if it does exist, that doesn't mean it has to equal $f(x)$.

Comment: @Hayden So let's say we had $f(x) = x$ where $f(3) = 5$, we'd say the domain is all real numbers, but it is not continuous on its own domain?

Comment: If $f(3)=5$, then you don't have $f(x)=x$ for each $x$. If you mean that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\neq 3$, and $f(3)=5$, then yes, it's domain would be all real numbers, but it won't be continuous at $3$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily. The domain of a function tells you over what values the function $f(x)$ exists, not where it is continuous. Take the piecewise function:

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & x<0\\
2 & x\geq0
\end{cases}$$

This function is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, but is not continuous at $x=0$. It still has a valid value: $f(0)=2$, but that doesn't make it continuous at that point.

For a function to be continuous at a point, its limit must be the same regardless of what direction of approach. In this case, $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}{f(x)}=1$ while $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}{f(x)}=2$, making it discontinuous at that point.

Comment: Does your last paragraph imply that the endpoints of a domain don't count for or against the continuity of the function, since at most they'd have a single one-sided limit defined?

Comment: Depends on the definition of "domain." For instance, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a well-defined function for all $x\in\mathbb{R},x>=0$. For the purposes of that domain, evaluating the continuity of the function at $f(x)=0$ only requires that the right-handed limit equal the value of the function: that is, that $lim_{x\to0^+}{f(x)}=f(x)$. When evaluating the domain of the function as the entire real line, then the function is actually discontinuous due to the left-hand limit not existing.

Comment: @user525966: for this reason while defining continuity we consider only the points in the domain. Thus $f(x) =\sqrt{x} $ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If a point is in the domain of a function, then it is not necessary that the function is continuous at the point.
However, it is clear that if a function is continuous at a point then the point is in the domain of the function. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly, because usually when you talk about the domain of the function, you are talking about the **natural domain** of the function, in other words, where the function is defined, but not necessarly continious. For example $f(x) = sign(x)$ is defined for all $x \in R$, but is not continious on $x  = 0$, then is not continious on it´s domain.
Actually you can take any step defined function such that is defined on a certain domain but is not continious on that set.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition.** A function $f$ is continuous on its domain $D$ if
$f$ is [continuous at every point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) $c\in D$.

**Example 1.** The function $f(x)=e^x$ (with domain $\mathbb R$) is continuous on its domain.

**Example 2.** Here is a function (with domain $\mathbb R$) that is *nowhere continuous*: the [Dirichlet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html) $D(x)$. This function can be defined as
$$
D(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if $x$ is rational } \\
0 & \text{ if $x$ is irrational. } 
\end{cases}
$$
These examples show that the words "continuous on its domain" are not superfluous.

Comment: How is it nowhere continuous? Is it some proof that between any two rational numbers there exists an irrational number, and between any two irrational numbers there exists a rational number?

Comment: Yes, indeed, between any two rational numbers there exists an irrational number, and vice versa. Here is a [nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDFSDopjklg) explaining why the Dirichlet function is nowhere continous. Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

A function is said to be continuous if it continues at each point. This means that over the domain. Functions that are not continuous do not exist for every x value over the domain. For example if a function is defined near an open interval (the circle that is not shaded on a graph) then the function is discontinuous. However, if a function is defined near a closed circle (the shaded circle of a graph) then that function is continuous. This problem usually occurs when trying to find the Domain and Range of a function or if a problem ask to graph the Domain and Range of a function.